# FreeBSD custom configure arguments

Tags: compilation, makefile, freebsd, configure

What is the best way in FreeBSD to compile programm from ports if I need some custom configure arguments which is not present in default `make config` window? For example I want compile php  with --enable-intl flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
make configure CONFIGURE_ARGS=--enable-intl
```

but i'm not sure if it will work. If not, edit `/usr/ports/lang/php5/Makefile` file and add `--enable-intl` to `CONFIGURE_ARGS` there. After that do not forget to `make clean`.

Comment: Thanks. I've edit Makefile by hands and than do make reinstall. All works fine

Comment: Don't forget that you have to re-do this edit after every update of the ports tree!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way **in this case** is to install the extension: `/usr/ports/devel/pecl-intl`.

Generally, if you want a configure option that it not in the port, the best way is to submit a patch for the port Makefile that includes it as an option. That way you don't have to worry about re-applying the patch after every ports tree update, and other people can benefit from it as well.